# Are the Sri Yantras that are devoid of color fillings defective?

Tags: scripture, devi, tantra, sri-vidya, yantra

[Sri Yantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Yantra) is probably the most well-known among all yantras. It is   also called the king of yantras.

The presiding deity of the yantra is [Sri Lalita Mahatripurasundari or Sri Rajarajeswari Devi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripura_Sundari).

A Sri Yantra can be inscribed on a metal plate  and it can also have the 3-dimensional Meru form.

**Meru Sri Yantra:**

[image]

Given below are pics of two kinds of Sri Yantra that i have found on net (that are available for shopping). One of which has some color fillings and one is without them.

**PIC 1:**

[image]

**PIC 2:**

[image]

**Questions:**

1) Is the **PIC 2** Yantra defective? If yes, which Scripture prescribes what color should fill in which triangles of the Sri Yantra?

2) What do these different colors signify?

Comment: The best place to check would be the Shakta Agamas associated with the Sri Vidya sect.

Comment: The  Sri Vidya texts will of course have the rules. But I want to know which particular text or texts? like is it the Vamakeswara Tantram? I want to know because i don't have this text in particular.@KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: If Sri Vidya texts are too difficult to look in, another place to check would be the works of Bhaskararaya, who was the most prominent Sri Vidya Acharya.

Comment: @Rickross - I don't know much about Yantras.But I think pic.2 is not defective.The shape and geometry is important in the case of yantras.I think the the color's are separating different geometrical shapes.So with the colors its easy to visualize the yantra .So they are just for visual aid. Its my guess , but i will also search about ur question.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes as long as the geometries are drawn correctly the Yantras should not be defective. But afaik this colored patterns are mentioned in Scriptures only. So without the appropriate color fillings the yantras mite be less effective.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am adding my own **partial** answer based on information found on [Astrojyoti.com](http://www.astrojyoti.com/sriyantracolours.htm)

According to the author of the above article, the correct color fillings for Sri Yantra has been given in various Scriptures. But the author quotes only the [Mantra Mahodadhi](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/mantra-mahodadhi-HAA381/).

> For quite sometime I have been observing the many multi coloured sri
>   yantra pictures published in the various websites and tantra books.
>
> **While one is free to visualize HER as one wants, being a sri vidya
>   upasaka I thought of making a sri chakra with the right colours as
>   described in the various scriptures. The following is the outcome of
>   my study of several tantrik scriptures, mantra mahodadhi and also the
>   writings of Sri Amritananda.**

The author then gives the following list of colors that should fill the different avaranas (layers) of the Sri Chakra.

> 1st Avarana the outer square with three lines and 4 gates is brown.
>   The outer line is white (though the colour of the 10 deities here is
>   like molten gold), the middle line is orange red like the rising sun
>   and the inner line is yellow like the colour of butter.
>
> 2nd Avarana the 16 petal lotus is pink like lotus flower.
>
> 3rd Avarana the 8 petal lotus is red – the colour of Bandhuka flowers.
>
> 4th Avarana the 14 cornered triangle is colour green like the colour
>   of glow worms.
>
> 5th Avarana the outer 10 corners triangle is red like Japakusuma
>   flowers.
>
> 6th Avarana the inner 10 corners triangle is colour blue (though the
>   deities here have the lusture of 1000 rising suns).
>
> 7th Avarana the 8 corners triangle is colour red like Dadini flowers.
>
> 8.The innermosst triangle is white.
>
> 9.The Bindu the central point is red like Sindoor. I made the above picture by colouring the 9 avaranas accordingly. The background
>   colours are of course to give a visual effect.
>
> [image]

So, the **PIC 2** Sri Yantra might not be defective but it can certainly be thought of as being less effective than the one which have the correct colors.

**But i am not satisfied with this answer. And, i am expecting more answers from other users which have explicit quotes from the relevant Kaula Scriptures.**

Comment: Ok , But one more thing is the yantras are not always drawn on paper so that these could be painted.They are also engraved in stone's , Drawn in Rangoli patterns , Metal engraving , Marble engravings etc.so in all such a cases at least in ancient times there was no scope to paint.i.e. although its better to paint yantras drawn on paper ,but in the other mediums its not possible & necessary & as u said it might be less effective.

Comment: Yes agree. and i am not satisfied with this answer .@SwiftPushkar waiting for more answers.